# Find some infinite series dependency

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $$x(a)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n a^n$$and$$y(a)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_na^n} {4n}$$ can I find $y(x)$ and how?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  If $x=x(a)$ then $z=x(a^4)$.  There's no hope of getting a formula for $z$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: I thought about it but I am not sure, maybe this is possible...

Comment: If $x(a)=\log(a),$ then $z(a)=\log(a^4)=4\log(a)$.  If $x(a)=\cos(a)$ then $z(a)=\cos(a^4)\neq4\cos(a)$.  How can you expect there to be a formula for $z$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: Fixed. Thank you

Comment: Think about differentiating $y$ with respect to $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y=f(x)/4$ when $f$ means that in every index of the sum you divide by $n$ so actually $y=\int \frac{xda}{4a}$, that because when you divide by $a$ you decrease every power of $a$ by one then, when you apply the integral you increase those powers back and divide by the power.

Comment: I don't get the answer sorry

Comment: @MarineGalantin I fixed it